# Not getting the button state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some code as follows:

```
<div class="onOffContainer">
 <div class="onOffClass" id="onoffBtn1" value="No" ></div>
 <div class="onOffClass" id="onoffBtn2" value="No" ></div>
</div>
```

I am using "onOffClass" class to get the state of button containing this class.

My code works for single button. If I add multiple buttons, the code does not work

Can anyone point out the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you getting the state of the bottom ?

Comment: can you post the working code!

Comment: you have to post `jQuery` code as well.